# How to simulate random normal variate Python

Tags: python, random, simulation, normal-distribution

First of all, I am extremely new with coding. I received an assignment to "Simulate many normally distributed random numbers, then calculate mean and standard deviation." using Python. To begin with, I'm having some difficulties interpreting the question.

Anyway, I think I've figured out how to generate a wished number of random numbers from a standard normal distribution using a for loop (though I'm not sure this is what's asked for). What I'm struggling with is to use these numbers for calculations - since they are random I don't know how to use lists.

Comment: Exactly, sampling works fine, but I would like to for every run calculate the mean and std. dev for the sampled data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the random numbers using [`random.gauss`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.gauss). For example I'll create a list of 10 random numbers, with a mean of `10` and standard deviation of `1`

```
>>> import random
>>> nums = [random.gauss(10, 1) for _ in range(10)]
>>> nums
[11.959067391283675, 9.736968009359552, 9.034607376861388, 9.431664007796622, 11.522646114577977, 9.777134678502273, 10.954304068858296, 9.641278997034552, 10.671349950944085, 10.795117781051463]
```

Then you can use the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) library to calculate mean and standard deviation.

```
>>> import statistics as stats

>>> avg = stats.mean(nums)
>>> avg
10.352413837626989   # pretty close to 10

>>> stddv = stats.stdev(nums)
>>> stddv
0.9667002670583574   # pretty close to 1
```

You can see that if I generated a lot of random numbers, assuming the `random` library has a good implementation of sampling numbers from a desired distribution, you will get back approximately the mean and standard deviation you used to describe the original distribution.